# Ошибка при создании DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.x, numpy

У меня есть код, который считает отток.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

churned_array = []

previous =  pd.read_excel('previous.xlsx')

current = pd.read_excel('current.xlsx')

churned_idx = np.isin(current, previous, invert=True)

churned = current[churned_idx] 

churned_array.append(len(churned))

churn_table = pd.DataFrame({'churn':churned
                           }, columns=['churn'])

churn_table.to_csv('churn.csv',index=False)
```

после выполнения строки

```
churn_table = pd.DataFrame({'churn':churned
                               }, columns=['churn'])
```

получаю ошибку

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: а что выдает `churned.shape`?

Comment: (38041, 1) вот это

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** также данная ошибка возникает если передать 2D матрицу при вызове конструктора, когда конструктор ожидает 1D вектор:

```
In [1]: churned = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])

In [2]: churned.shape
Out[2]: (3, 1)

In [3]: pd.DataFrame({'churn':churned}, columns=['churn'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Нужно правильно вызывать конструктор - либо передавать в качестве значений столбца 1D вектор:

```
In [4]: pd.DataFrame({'churn':churned.ravel()})
Out[4]:
   churn
0      1
1      2
2      3

In [5]: churned.ravel().shape
Out[5]: (3,)
```

либо передать конструктору 2D матрицу и наименования столбцов:

```
In [8]: pd.DataFrame(churned, columns=['churn'])
Out[8]:
   churn
0      1
1      2
2      3
```

---

Данная ошибка возникает в том случае если все переданные конструктору значения являются скалярами. В вашем случае это обозначает, что переменная `churned` - содержит скалярное значение, например `3.14`, вместо `list` / `numpy.ndarray` / `pandas.Series` / etc.

```
churned = np.pi
df = pd.DataFrame({'churn':churned}, columns=['churn'])
```

выдаёт:

> ```
> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
> ```

В этом случае надо явно задать индекс:

```
In [106]: df = pd.DataFrame({'churn':churned}, index=[0])

In [107]: df
Out[107]:
      churn
0  3.141593
```

Comment: Ловлю вот такую ошибку Data must be 1-dimensional
churned это numpy array заполненный числами int64

Comment: @ДенисСтадник, приведите в вопросе __воспроизводимый__ пример данных

Comment: churn_table = pd.DataFrame({'churn':churned}, index=[0])